# How to generate C++ function automatically?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, code-generation

I want to write a c++ matrix operation code, some operation are the same for some function. I wonder whether there are some method to merge them? For example:

```
void add1(vector<vector<double> > &m){
    for(int i = 0; i < m.size(); ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < m[i].size(); ++j){
            m[i][j] += 1.0;
        }
    }
}

void minus1(vector<vector<double> > &m){
    for(int i = 0; i < m.size(); ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < m[i].size(); ++j){
            m[i][j] -= 1.0;
        }
    }
}
```

The two pieces of code is almost the same. How can I avoid to rewrite it for two times? Are there something like template that can generate code automatically?

Comment: You can use a 1D array to store the elements of the matrices (reduce to 1 loop instead of 2 nested loops) and then use lambdas.

Comment: You realize that you are passing `m` by value, right?   That means that your function will make a copy of the vector passed in and not update it on return.

Comment: @selbie sorry for not recognize that. But my problem remain.

Comment: You are trying to write C code with C++ syntax and C++ containers

Answer (score 10):

You can define a function template and put the core logic of iterating over the elements in that function.

The template parameter can be functor which can be used to define what happens for each specific call.

```
// Change m to be a reference so the modifications to the elements
// are visible in the calling function.

template <typename Functor>
void for_each_member(vector<vector<double> >& m, Functor functor)
{
   for(std::size_t i = 0; i < m.size(); ++i){
      for(std::size_t j = 0; j < m[i].size(); ++j){
         functor(m[i][j]);
      }
   }
}

void add1(vector<vector<double> >& m){
   for_each_member(m, [](double& item) { item += 1.0;});
}

void minus1(vector<vector<double> >& m){
   for_each_member(m, [](double& item) { item -= 1.0;});
}
```

Comment: I have implemented a version with functor, but it runs very slow. The speed is almost 1/5 of the direct version.

Comment: @maple This is a separate question. It should not. I guess you are doing something wrong, either in code or in measurements, or both.

Comment: @Drop I think during each iteration, it will invoke a function, so the speed may be slow? Is that true?

Comment: @maple - there's most certainly tradeoffs between code re-use, elegance of C++, and performance.  If you want a performance optimized solution stop using `vector` and fall back to traditional C programming mechanisms that operate directly on pointers and/or with macros.  The C++ camp on Stack Overflow is more inclined to give you the elegant C++ answer rather than the most optimized code.

Comment: May I suggest using a range based for loop?

Comment: @R Sahu will Functor& functor speed up the program?

Answer (score 3):

You could generalize in the following manner:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
void for_each_element(std::vector<std::vector<T>> &m, F &&f) {
  std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), [f] (auto &&v) {
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), f);
  });
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52b2e6d9044e2ae9)

Mind however, that representing a matrix as a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` is not very cache friendly, since you disparse the rows of the matrix all over the memory. It would be better if you had a custom matrix class that internally would use one `std::vector` and would overload the subscript operators for [row/column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) access.

Comment: Why are you using forwarding references, if you don't use `std::forward`?

Comment: @MikeMB for proxy object functors, but where you would use `std::forward` in the code shown?

Comment: I'd neither use `std::forward`, nor forwarding reference, but just pass by value. My point is, that - as you are not moving or forwarding from `f` - I don't see, what `F &&f` gains you compared to e.g. `const F& f`.

Comment: @MikeMB: `f` can have mutable state.

Comment: @Jarod42: Thats also true for `const F& f`. In particular, any operations are performed on copies on `f` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a func with the second argument and then add it to each member of matrix.

Comment: But the program will become very very slowly.

Comment: @maple.  The use of `<vector>` is the bigger hit on performance than an argument parameter.  That, and not passing the vector by reference.

Comment: @maple: What compiler are you using and have you verified in both cases, that the addition/subtraction is actually performed? (i.e. Print the original and the resulting matrix)

Answer (score 0):

You could define it this way

```
template <template <class> class pred>
void apply(vector<vector<double>> & m) {
    for (auto & i : m)
        for (auto & j : i)
            j = pred<double>()(j, 1.0);
}
```

For addition, call

```
apply<std::plus>(m);
```

similarly, for substraction

```
apply<std::minus>(m);
```

you can also use other function objects from [`<functional>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional)

See a working [DEMO](http://ideone.com/nnkjby).

Answer (score 0):

You could also write an iterator for your matrix. This is not complete but gives you an idea:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template< class _T >
class Matrix
{
public:
    std::vector< std::vector< _T > > m_matrix;
    void alloc( size_t rows, size_t cols )
    {
        m_matrix.resize( rows );
        std::for_each( m_matrix.begin(), m_matrix.end(), [cols](std::vector<_T> &t){t.resize(cols);});
    }
    class iterator
    {
    public:
        iterator( std::vector< std::vector< _T > > & v ):
            m_vbegin( v.begin() ),
            m_vi( v.begin() ),
            m_i( m_vi->begin() ),
            m_vend( v.end() )
        {}
        iterator& operator++()
        {
            if ( ++m_i == m_vi->end() )
            {
                if ( ++m_vi != m_vend )
                    m_i = m_vi->begin();
            }
            return (*this);
        }
        void gotobegin()
        {
            m_vi=m_vbegin;
            m_i=m_vi->begin();
        }
        void gotoend()
        {
            m_vi=m_vend;
        }
        _T & operator*()
        {
            return *m_i;
        }
        bool operator==(const iterator & rhs )
        {
            if ( m_vi==rhs.m_vi && (m_vi==m_vend || m_i==rhs.m_i) )
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        bool operator!=(const iterator & rhs )
        {
            return !( *this == rhs );
        }
    private:
        typename std::vector< std::vector< _T > >::iterator m_vi;
        const typename std::vector< std::vector< _T > >::iterator m_vbegin;
        const typename std::vector< std::vector< _T > >::iterator m_vend;
        typename std::vector< _T >::iterator m_i;
    };
    iterator begin(){ return iterator(m_matrix); }
    iterator end(){ iterator ret(m_matrix); ret.gotoend(); return ret;}
};
int main( void )
{
    Matrix<double> matrix;
    matrix.alloc( 4000, 4000 );
    std::for_each( matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), []( double &t){ t=1.0;} );
    std::for_each( matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), []( double &t){ t+=1.0;} );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the other answers. You can also use a `std::function` (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). Here you have to define the return type as well as the parameter types. Using this you can pass anything that is callable.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using matrix = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;

void for_each_member(matrix& m, std::function<void(double&)> functor)
{
  for (auto &vec : m)
    for (auto &element : vec)
      functor(element);
}

static void sub(double &ele)
{
  --ele;
}

int main()
{
  matrix m = { {1,2}, {3,4} };

  for_each_member(m, [](auto &ele) { ++ele; });
  for_each_member(m, [](auto &ele) {std::cout << ele << " "; });

  std::cout << "\n";

  for_each_member(m, sub);
  for_each_member(m, [](auto &ele) {std::cout << ele << " "; });
  std::cout << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Disclaimer: I'm breaking some C++ encapsulation offered by vector to show a *potentially* faster solution that offers what you want. Some purists that hang out on the C++ tags on SO are sure to knock me for showing you some *ahem* C code.  But I'm going to show you anyway.  You can make your own decision for yourself.

```
inline void add_to_every_element(vector<double>* rows, size_t m_size, double d)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
    {
        size_t row_size = rows[i].size();
        double* row = rows[i].data();
        for (size_t j = 0; j < row_size; j++)
        {
            row[j] += d;
        }
    }
}

void add1(vector<vector<double> > &m)
{
    add_to_every_element(m.data(), m.size(), 1.0);
}

void minus1(vector<vector<double>>& m)
{
    add_to_every_element(m.data(), m.size(), -1.0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have a lot of other operation, except + and -.

Comment: Then go with R. Sahu's solution and optimize as you need to.

Comment: I'm not against breaking abstractions, if it increases performance, noticeably but I'd like to know why you think this might be more efficient.

Comment: @MikeMB - That's a fair question. My hypothesis, based on experience, is that I suspect that multiple invocations of `size()` and `[]` operators in a loop generates generates a substantial amount of code.  In release builds, a lot of this overhead simply gets inlined and becomes less of an issue.    My initial test harness is consistently showing my loop is 10% faster than the OP's for *large* matrices such as 100x100.  For *smaller* 3x3 matrices, the running time is consistently the same for a release build between each implementation.  Happy to discuss offline.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I know to avoid calling `size()` repeatedly in timecritical code, but expected `operator[]` to be optimized away completely. In any case: have you tried to compare it against a range-base-for-loop? It gives me the exact same timings as your solution.